# Looping through nested dictionary - Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have written a function which takes 2 arguments:

```
myfunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Now, I would like to pass through this function keys and values from a dictionary:

```
    pairs = {
        "pair1": {"key1": "value1"},
        "pair2": {"key2": "value2"},    
        "pair3": {"key3": "value3"},
}
```

so that I would run `my function` on every combination of `key & value`.I tried to achieve it with this loop:

```
for key, value in pairs.items():
    results = myfunction(key, value)
```

which must be an incorrect way given the empty output. How should I propely call key and value into the loop?

Comment: Wdym by *an incorrect way*? Why are you getting empty output? You can post your `myfunction()` so that we can see why it returns no output.

Comment: Thanks @AbhyudayVaish, I just red in stackoverflow how to do that so I will use this option from now on :)

Comment: What intended output do you want? Do you want key1, value1; key2, value2....?

Comment: The output of the function should be a dataframe- the solution posted below works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. Printing is just for you to understand what's going on.
In addition, a simple google search would've showed you some solid information.

```py
for item in pairs.values():
   for key, value in item.items():
       print(key + " " + value)
```

Good luck.

see this: (Credit- GeeksforGeeks) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionary/